# Windows 10 killing grub

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot, grub

I'm trying to run a dual boot system with w10 and Ubuntu. Both system works, secure boot is disabled and legacy support enabled, but every time i boot windows10 it just kills grub so the next time i try to boot grub i need to repair it with a live cd of linux. The main problem is that every time windows boots, grub cant recognize the file system (obviusly i have to manually boot grub instead of the windows boot manager).
I didn't try with: `Bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` since last time i had to reinstall since i couldn't get it back to work.